# dynamic array of a nested class with an array in it? Can it be done?

Tags: arrays, class, pointers, dynamic, nested

This code compiles but crashes instantly. I've only tried it on `devcppPortable`. I am trying to make a class that can store a lot of complex data (i.e. an object that has multiple property sets and each set carries multiple figures).

Each object created would have a unique number of property sets and internal property values. I would like to be able to shape the class upon declaration so as not to allocate a bunch of unused space. Is something like this even possible?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class a
{
    public:
        int amount;
        struct b
        {
            int max;
            int* prop;
            b() {}
            void set(int&);
            ~b(){delete prop;}
        };
        b* property;
        a(int amt, int max0, int max1=0, int max2=0);
        ~a(){delete property;}
};

int main()
{
    a object(2, 3, 5);
    return 0;
}

a::a(int amt, int max0, int max1, int max2)
{
    amount = amt;
    property = new b[amt];

    switch(amt)
    {
        case 3:
            property[2].set(max2);
        case 2:
            property[1].set(max1);
        case 1:
            property[0].set(max0);
    }
}

void a::b::set(int& m) {max = m; prop = new int[max];}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocate `property` with `new[]` but deleting it with `delete`, not `delete[]`